# Need to delete this file to be able to backup data on TWRP

Tags: twrp, system, files

My Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro is rooted with TWRP as recovery. Unfortunately, after a system update, I became unable to access my system. I was only able to access TWRP and the files through it.

While creating a backup with TWRP, I encounter the following error

```
I:Error adding file '/data/anr/3i6xjEcwwZbkn6mZ,+ccwD' to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/c51c11bd/2020-05-05--09-33-29/data.ext4.win000'
Error creating backup.
I:ERROR tarList for thread ID 0
Error creating backup.
I:InfoManager saving '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/c51c11bd/2020-05-05--09-33-29/data.info'
createTarFork() process ended with ERROR: 255
Backup Failed. Cleaning Backup Folder.
I:Copying file /tmp/recovery.log to /data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/c51c11bd/2020-05-05--09-33-29/recovery.log
```

I need to know where this file is. Without it, I can backup my data partition. I've tried OrangeFox and it tells me the same thing.

I've been looking through TWRP but was unable to find such file. In TWRP, I browsed the folder through the install button and it was empty, nothing was showing at all.

How can I find the location of the folder and delete the contents so I could proceed to backup my data?

Comment: @RBBE in TWRP mount `/data` and browse to `/data/anr`. You can delete all files there as those are just logs of app crashes. Or at least delete those with special characters in their names like the one you mentioned. Isn't that file there in `/data/anr/`?

Comment: I believe the "install" button only shows zip and compatible image files for flashing & sideloading purposes, not showing all other files.

Comment: @RBBE from your comments, your actual question is "how to browse to /data/anr/ folder?"

Comment: Yeah th original intent was to find the location of the folder and delete the contents so I could proceed to backup my data.

Comment: the browser is in *TWRP - Advanced - Filemanager* and the *option menu* lower right corner. btw for full backup don't forget *'adb pull -a /sdcard'* afterwards (not included in *data.ext4.win*)

Answer (score 0):

just mount /data and type `rm` followed by the file name in single quotes. TWRP has a build-in Terminal, but i recommend to do it from adb shell

```
adb shell rm '/data/anr/3i6xjEcwwZbkn6mZ,+ccwD'
```

Comment: Where can I get ADB shell?

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads